# Magento 1.9.2.1 Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: paypal, upgrade, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I have been working to move my production site to 1.9.2.1, so I upgraded my staging site and everything went seamlessly. Granted I am not a huge fan of the new email template and having to use a cron job to send emails (which was another problem I already solved).

After upgrading staging to 1.9.2.1, I went to `System -> Configuration -> SALES -> Payment Methods` and immediately a popup window appears (shown below).

[image: Screenshot]

After receiving this error, I tried to re-enable my Paypal Payments Pro (Express Checkout) but it was already enabled. So I try to Save Configuration and when the page reloads the popup appears again.

I also tried to re-enter my API Settings with no luck.

Note: Before I went to `System -> Configuration -> SALES -> Payment Methods` my Paypal Express Checkout button was showing as usual. But now after travelling to Payment Methods, the button is not showing anymore. Unfortunately, I did not have a chance to test to see if it functioned before I went to Payment Methods.

Has anyone else had this issue when upgrading from 1.8.1 (or any version) to 1.9.2.1? If so would you kindly respond with a fix, or point me in the right direction? If you need any more information, I would be happy to assist.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the Magento cache? I would also try maybe disabling the Pro with Express Checkout, enable Express Checkout only and see if that works with no error. If so, then disable Express Checkout only and then enable the Pro with Express Checkout again.

Comment: @PayPal_MSI_Tiffany - Thank you very much for your response. Yes I tried clearing cache with no luck. But after I disabled Pro, then enable Express only, I did not receive the error. I also tried re-enabling Pro and now everything is working like before. I have Pro enabled again without receiving any errors. Thanks again!

Comment: That's great news! I'm glad that worked for you.